# gcc warning flags for implicit conversions

Tags: c++, gcc, type-conversion, gcc-warning

I recently had a bug in a similar context to next one:

```
double getSomeValue()
{
    return 4.0;
}
...
std::string str;
str = getSomeValue();
```

As you can see here is easy to spot the problem, but in a large code base where `getSomeValue()` is not in the same file with the calling code it might be difficult to spot this `double` to `std::string` silent conversion. GCC compiles this code fine with `-Wall -Wextra -Werror` (sample output here, I don't know what warning flags were used: http://ideone.com/BTXBFk).

How may I force GCC to emit warnings for these dangerous implicit conversions? I tried `-Wconversion`, but it is very strict and it causes errors in most included headers for common cases like `unsigned - 1`. Is there a weaker version of `-Wconversion`?

Comment: It is actually `double` → `char` → `string` conversion. First one can be caught by `-Wfloat-conversion` which is also enabled by `-Wconversion`

Comment: @Revolver_Ocelot Thank you, this flag seems to be the one I'm searching. Unfortunately it's not available in GCC 4.8.2

Comment: @DieterLücking I specified in the question that I can't use -Wconversion because I get lots of errors for unsigned - 1 like constructs in many included headers.

Comment: why is this tagged brace-initialization when it actually is not using brace-initialization   (and there would be no issue if it were, since braced initialization prevents narrowing conversions)

Comment: @M.M It was edited and it should not be -  the real context was something like `getReference() = getValue();` where left was std::string and right was double

Comment: @Revolver_Ocelot: Why `std::string str=99;` fails in compilation but  `std::string str; str=99; ` compiles fine? What is the reason?

Comment: @Felics: very good question. Learned something new Today. BTW Why `std::string str=99;` fails in compilation but  `std::string str; str=99; ` compiles fine? What is the reason? !!!

Comment: @Destructor because there are no constructor taking single integral value (closest one takes char __and__ size_t), but there is an assigment operator taking single char.

Comment: @Destructor std::string was designed a long time ago and has a lot of weird things, with hindsight we would have done it differently

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the `-Wfloat-conversion` flag, or the broader **`-Wconversion`**.

However, note that with C++11 **uniform initialization brace syntax**, you get a warning "out of the box", without the `-Wconversion` flag; e.g.:

```
#include <string>

double getSomeValue() {
    return 4.0;
}

int main() {   
    std::string str{ getSomeValue() }; // C++11 brace-init
}
```

> ```
> C:\Temp\CppTests>g++ -std=c++11 test.cpp
> test.cpp: In function 'int main()':
> test.cpp:8:35: warning: narrowing conversion of 'getSomeValue()' from 'double' t
> o 'char' inside { } [-Wnarrowing]
>      std::string str{ getSomeValue() };
>                                    ^
> ```

Comment: This doesn't help with `str = getSomeValue();`, which is assignment rather than initialization  (Presumably there are cases in OP's code where the assignment comes some time after the variable is already in use, so it can't be replaced with initialization)

Comment: @M.M: Probably in those cases something like this might work for the OP: `str = std::string{ getSomeValue() };`. Anyway, I consider the use of `-Wconversion` a good option.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `-Wconversion` and avoid error for `unsigned - 1` with `-Wno-sign-conversion`, like specified [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html).